# Create GeoTIFF from LIDAR file

Tags: c#, .net, geotiff, lidar

Generally I'm trying create raster from LIDAR cloud (files with extension .las) to geoTif. It is new to me and I don't know how I should start. For now I read all points from las file and I check all point by dimention 'Z' and each highest point draw in tif file. For create tif i use GDAL library from QGIS.

In LASTool and I found app which convert LAS to TIF but it is paid. I need something what is free. Maybe somebody had the same problem and he will share solution?

Moreover I need to my tiff file had tiles. So if somebody also had some code I will be grateful.

EDIT:

Thanks @chambbj , generally it is good suggestion because PDAL is great but this solution create me tif in grays colors. but I need something what will consider all colors in LAS file. I saw filters (colorization) but it not work :( maybe i'm doing some wrong? I don't know. 
Would be great, if I able to separet all point in cloud by max Z dimension and create tif file.

Example:
For now I have something like this
[image]

but I need some like this:
[image]

Each pixel is 5cm2

Comment: Have you tried this option? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170706/irregular-xyz-point-data-to-raster-tif-lastools-alternative

Comment: yes, I read about FUSION (FUSION/LDV ) but I can't get any files of library. moreover their website isn't compatible z current browsers. I have only their documentation. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [PDAL](https://www.pdal.io), using the [GDAL writer stage](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html). There exists a [tutorial](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/dtm/dtm.html) on the topic, which you may find informative.

The basic pipeline JSON would look something like

```
{
    "pipeline":[
        "input.las",
        {
            "type":"writers.gdal",
            "filename":"output.tif",
            "resolution":2.0,
            "output_type":"max"
        }
    ]
}
```

which can be executed with the PDAL [pipeline](https://www.pdal.io/apps/pipeline.html) command

```
pdal pipeline pipeline.json
```